# CSSRule is not getting updated with new background-color value typescript

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I want to change CSS style (background-color) for certain text on page dynamically. For that I'm trying to change CSSRule. Since, there are some 10 CSSRules present for required style, I am accessing desired CSSRule, using selectedText. Following is a code:

```
  changeRule() {
    let stylesheet: CSSStyleSheet = <CSSStyleSheet>this.stylesheet.sheet;
    let ruleLength: any = <CSSStyleSheet>this.stylesheet.sheet.cssRules.length;
    console.log(ruleLength)
    for(let i = 0; i < ruleLength; i++) {
      let currentTag: any = this.stylesheet.sheet.cssRules[i].selectorText as CSSStyleSheet
      let chosenTag: any = (`#text `+`[data-tag-id="${this.selectedTag.id}"]`)
      if(currentTag === chosenTag) {
        console.log("Rule matched");
        console.log(<CSSStyleSheet>this.stylesheet.sheet.cssRules[i].style.backgroundColor);
        let changedTag: any = <CSSStyleDeclaration>this.stylesheet.sheet.cssRules[i].style.backgroundColor
        changedTag = "initial";
        break;
      }      
    }
    console.log(<CSSStyleSheet>this.stylesheet.sheet)
  }
```

But after executing this function, there is no change in corresponding CSSRule. BackgroundColor is not getting updated. Moreover, I am getting compile time error for cssRules[i] as "Property cssRules does not exist on type StyleSheet". I'm using angular2 with typescript

Can someone please suggest me something for this?

Comment: because when you store backgroundColor into changedTag, it is a string.... it is not a reference to the property...

Comment: Don't do this. Anything you are trying to do can be done with regular CSS classes. Mucking directly with the style sheet is an anti-pattern and code smell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're updating the variable, not the rule property. Change

```
let changedTag: any = <CSSStyleDeclaration>this.stylesheet.sheet.cssRules[i].style.backgroundColor
changedTag = "initial";
```

to

```
<CSSStyleDeclaration>this.stylesheet.sheet.cssRules[i].style.backgroundColor = "initial";
```

JavaScript example (using `"yellow"` instead of `"initial"`):

```js
function changeRule() {
    let stylesheet = this.stylesheet.sheet;
    let ruleLength = this.stylesheet.sheet.cssRules.length;
    console.log(ruleLength)
    for (let i = 0; i < ruleLength; i++) {
        let currentTag = this.stylesheet.sheet.cssRules[i].selectorText
        let chosenTag = (`#text ` + `[data-tag-id="${this.selectedTag.id}"]`)
        if (currentTag === chosenTag) {
            console.log("Rule matched");
            console.log(this.stylesheet.sheet.cssRules[i].style.backgroundColor);
            this.stylesheet.sheet.cssRules[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log(this.stylesheet.sheet)
}
setTimeout(changeRule.bind({
  stylesheet: {
    sheet: findSheet()
  },
  selectedTag: {
    id: "foo"
  }
}), 1000);
// In case stack snippets move the sheet around:
function findSheet() {
  var sheets = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.styleSheets);
  var sheet;
  sheets.some(function(s) {
    if (s.cssRules[0].selectorText == '#text [data-tag-id="foo"]') {
      sheet = s;
      return true;
    }
  });
  return sheet;
}
```

```css
#text [data-tag-id="foo"] {
  color: red;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="text">
  <div data-tag-id="foo">This is foo</div>
  <div data-tag-id="bar">This is bar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not able to use this snippet since its JS stuff. Initially I was also assigning "yellow" directly to backgroundColor, but it was not working. It was rather giving me compile error under "=" symbol. But there was no error message. I have added now a button, on which I'm calling this changeRule method. <button md-button (click)="changeRule()">Change color</button>, but color doesn't seems to change either. Could you please suggest ?

Comment: @NilakshiNaphade: TypeScript is JavaScript plus type annotations and a tiny bit of further syntax sugar. The working example above can trivially be turned back into TypeScript by adding back the type annotations.

Comment: Okay. It worked. The issue was type casting to <CSSStyleSheet> and <CSSStyleDeclaration>. If I remove that then color is changing. But I have one more issue. I'm getting compile error for cssRules[i] in a statement "this.stylesheet.sheet.cssRules[i].selectorText". Though its working, but compilation will fail if I again start the npm server. What could be the problem here?

Comment: @NilakshiNaphade: That'll depend a lot on ***what*** error you're getting.

Comment: Error is: "Property cssRules does not exist on type StyleSheet"

Comment: @NilakshiNaphade: You need to review the casting syntax in TypeScript, your casts are not properly scoped. For example, you have `let ruleLength: any = <CSSStyleSheet>this.stylesheet.sheet.cssRules.length;` which casts `length` to `<CSSStyleSheet>`. It should be `let ruleLength: any = (<CSSStyleSheet>this.stylesheet.sheet).cssRules.length;` That error is repeated in various other places. Also, don't use `any` unnecessarily. `ruleLength` is a `number`, it should be declared as such.